# GitHub and Git reporting two different statuses

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

My git repo is stating that it is clean, when checked from the commandline:

```
$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

But GitHub for mac is showing that a submodule needs to be added:

[image: GitHub spazzing out]

I prefer to use GitHub, but can't really proceed as the submodule is causing an issue as I can't seem to add it. Has anyone else ever come across this? How do I get them to both agree (as it's the same Git repo!)

Comment: Did you try a `git submodule update --init` first, and then check the status in your GitHub for Mac?

Comment: Tried that - didn't work :(. I have simply removed the submodule declaration within .gitmodules for now (to work around this issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your .git/config file and make sure the submodule is listed there. Add it if not. Ex:

[submodule "yoursubmodule"]
    url = git@github.com:[your repo]

Then do a git pull. It may be that there is no 'reference' to the submodule in the root project, so it is not able to find it.

Comment: Haha that was it! No idea how that got messed up! However, I re-added it, pulled it and all the code was new (for this submodule) which funked everything up. I think I'll remove ALL submodules and just keep static copies as I know they won't change... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the submodule doesn't work, you would not only need to remove it from the `.gitmodules` file, but you would also need to remove it from the index:

```
git rm --cached assets/chosen
```

(no trailing '`/`')

That is because a submodule is a [special entry (gitlink) in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) (to record the SHA1 associated with said submodule).